# django project url error

Tags: python, html, django

I created a project and created an application orders.

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'orders/index.htm')
def orders(request):
    return render(request, 'orders/order.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from orders import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^index.htm/', views.index, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^order.html/', views.orders, name='orders'),)
```

I used a ready to use site template.the link for 2 pages are:
[index.htm](http://tempsend.com/0E11C84D0E)         index.htm is Dashboard
[order.html](http://tempsend.com/30BE723D9D)         order.html is Orders
[image]
when i go to link localhost:8000/orders/ , I click on orders the link looks like this.

[image]

and further click on two links in left pane multiple times, the resulting url look like this:

localhost:8000/orders/order.html/order.html 
localhost:8000/orders/order.html/index.htm

[image]
[image]

I want to remove the order.html from middle so that it looks like:

localhost:8000/orders/index.htm
localhost:8000/orders/order.html

Comment: Is this in your main project's folder urls.py or in your app/urls.py? If this is your app/urls.py, please show your project/urls.py file as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links in your template do not have a leading slash, which means they are relative to the current directory.

If you are on the page with the URL http://localhost:8000/index.html/ and click on a hyperlink with `href="order.html"`, it will take you to 
http://localhost:8000/index.html/order.html

To fix it you must either

- Add a slash to the links in your template, e.g. `<a href="/order.html">`
- or drop the trailing slash from your URL definition in `urls.py`, e.g.

  `url(r'^index.htm', views.index, name='dashboard')`

I suggest you use the template tag `url` in your templates instead of hard coding links.
If possible, I would also remove the `.htm` extension from both templates and `urls.py`

Answer (score 1):

Change the following in `urls.py` file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from orders import views
      urlpatterns = patterns('',
      url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
      url(r'^index/$', views.index, name='dashboard'),
      url(r'^order/$', views.orders, name='orders'),)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "didn't work". It gives the same result or any error ?

Comment: Elaborate what you mean - does it give the same as previous or it gives some error ? I am not getting what are you telling by "didn't work for me" !!!

Comment: Please check i have added screenshots.